# Consume a secured soap web service in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, webservice-client, ws-security

I am trying to consume a secured web service that requires me to provide username, password, and apitoken.

I have been trying to follow the tutorial on this [link](http://www.littlebigextra.com/consume-secure-soap-web-service-spring-boot-application/)

but am a newbie I wanted a tutorial that would hand-walk me. Is there any example out there that shows how to consume a secured soap web service using spring boot.

Comment: You can try searching for something along the lines of "spring boot soap client authentication"...